# Why my debounce function returns undefined value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here's my [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/hidden-shape-9ltte?file=/src/App.js:447-455):

The problem is input value should be displayed in 2 seconds, but it doesn't.
I tried to debug the value and it's undefined, but I can't figure out why.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Please also post the important parts of the code in the question. (PS I haven't downvoted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of the issue is that the function returned by `debounce` does not take any parameters and so when you pass in `value` to `delayHandler` it doesn't do anything.

Here is a working example:

```js
const { useState } = React;

function debounce(fn, ms) {
  let timer;
  return (...args) => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      fn.apply(this, args);
    }, ms);
  };
}

function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  const handleChange = e => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    delayHandler(value);
  };

  const delayHandler = debounce(setValue, 2000);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>Current value: {value}</p>
      <form>
        <input onChange={handleChange} />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

////////////////////////////////////////

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>React App</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow, that's exactly what I need, thank you so much! My silly fault that I forgot to pass arguments to the returned function :p But why did you move `let timer` outside `debounce`? Since I don't want to pollute the global namespace I put it inside and the code still works.

Comment: Excellent, glad to hear it did the trick. Good point about polluting the global namespace. I've moved `let timer` back inside `debounce`. I moved it outside while debugging and forgot to try moving it back after I got it working.

Answer (score 1):

well it's seem `delayHandler` is no a function that take the value as params and send it to `debounce` you should do like this and it will work:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

function debounce(fn, ms, ...args) {
  let timer;
  return () => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      timer = null;
      fn.apply(this, args);
    }, ms);
  };
}

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  const handleChange = e => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    delayHandler(value)();
  };

  const delayHandler = v =>
    debounce(
      value => {
        setValue(value);
      },
      2000,
      v
    );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>Current value: {value}</p>
      <form>
        <input value={value} onChange={handleChange} />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

so by passing v as argument to `debounce` it will apply it to `fn` function.

here full example : [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-lake-4fklj?file=/src/App.js:0-1056)

Answer (score 0):

```
function debounce(fn, ms, ...args) {
  let timer;
  return () => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      fn(...args);
    }, ms);
  };
}

const delayHandler = value =>
    debounce(
      value => {
        setValue(value);
      },
      2000,
      value
    )();
```

Here is the fix, when you call the debounce function you have to pass value as a parameter, otherwise the args will not contain the val.
By the way you don't have to implement this by yourself, you can use lodash debounce
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce